# error message display while running vagrant up

Tags: linux, installation, vagrant

Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 1895 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current project's Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding. You could
try 'vagrant reload' (equivalent of running a halt followed by an up)
so vagrant can attempt to auto-correct this upon booting. Be warned
that any unsaved work might be lost.
please how can i resolve this issue